# ejs won't print a new line in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a web app in Node.js/MySQL where users can upload their stories. They write in an HTML textarea tag. Now I'm trying to get the uploaded from the database using ejs into a script tag so I can do further 'processes'

```js
<script>
 var text = "<%=story.Content%>",
  result = anchorme.js(text);
 document.getElementById('story-content').innerHTML = twemoji.parse(result);
</script>
```

Problem is if the user hit enter to start on a new line while writing. It'll give me an error here in the text variable and nothing will be printed so how do I fix this?

Comment: You can't use inline variables like that for scripts, iirc.

Answer (score 2):

If you view source on the page so that you can see how the browser receives it, you'll see something like this - note the line feeds:

```
    var text = "I am a story over multiple lines
and that's what javascript gets confused about
because it can't figure out where the closing quotes are.

Let's not even go into what could happen when someone uses quotes!"
```

So you really just need a way to pass the story content to javascript without it breaking the page. Instead of just pushing out the string like this...

```
var text = "<%=story.Content%>"
```

...you can pass stuff to javascript in JSON format as that allows and escapes newlines into \r\n and quotes into \" and so-on. Note the use of `<%-` rather than `<%=` here because you don't want it to pass escaped HTML:

```
var text = <%-JSON.stringify({ content: story.Content })%>.content;
```

That passes an object with a nicely escaped string in it to your inline script for it to carry on processing.